# Count Number of Values and Return a Count as A Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a query that, effectively, combines the two below queries but I think I'm having writers block. I've tried a writing a sub query but to no avail. I've considered a Cross Tab query but I'd like to avoid anything that's too Access specific. I've tried a UNION but that didn't seem to work either. I highly suspect that it's just me being rubbish. I am tempted to try a SQL PIVOT but I've not tried them before and, judging by the way my day is going, I doubt I'll succeed.

Anyway, the queries that work for me are:

```
SELECT Operative.NAME, COUNT(*) AS [Yes to Left Tidy?]
FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
WHERE Q5 = 'yes'
GROUP BY Operative.NAME

SELECT Operative.NAME, COUNT(*) AS [No to Left Tidy?]
FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
WHERE Q5 = 'no'
GROUP BY Operative.NAME
```

If you want me to detail the table structures etc please let me know.

Comment: What union query did you try and what happened?

Comment: I think he wants Operative.NAME, count(no) , count(yes) in one row, a double join on the table that provides q5 would be enough though

Comment: could you give us your table structures and expected result from query please @Matt

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
    select * FROM
    (SELECT Operative.NAME, COUNT(*) AS [Yes to Left Tidy?],'YES' AS Y/N
    FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] 
    INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) 
    ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
    WHERE Q5 = 'yes'
    GROUP BY Operative.NAME)A,
    UNION
    (SELECT Operative.NAME, COUNT(*) AS [Yes to Left Tidy?],'NO' AS Y/N
    FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] 
    INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) 
    ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
    WHERE Q5 = 'no'
    GROUP BY Operative.NAME)B
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to group by Q5, e.g:

```
SELECT Operative.NAME, Q5 [Left Tidy?], COUNT(*)
FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
WHERE Q5 IN ('yes', 'no')
GROUP BY Q5, Operative.NAME
```

..if you want one pair of counts per row you could take these results and pivot them, e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Operative.NAME, Q5 [Left Tidy?], COUNT(*) c
FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
WHERE Q5 IN ('yes', 'no')
GROUP BY Q5, Operative.NAME) p
PIVOT (SUM(c) FOR [Left Tidy?] IN ([no], [yes])) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Standard SQL this would be `SUM(CASE WHEN Q5 = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, this simply sums ones or zeroes based on the condition. Access doesn't support `CASE`, but `IIF` should provide the same result:

```
SELECT Operative.NAME, 
   SUM(IIF(Q5 = 'yes', 1, 0)) AS [Yes to Left Tidy?],
   SUM(IIF(Q5 = 'no', 1, 0)) AS AS [No to Left Tidy?]
FROM Operative INNER JOIN ([Survey Results] INNER JOIN JOBS ON [Survey Results].Job_Number = JOBS.Job_Number) ON Operative.USERID = JOBS.SCHEDULEITEMS_ASSIGNEDWORKERID
WHERE Q5 IN ('yes', 'no') -- only needed if other values exist
GROUP BY Operative.NAME
```